# Need to split a string containing numbers and alphabets into two

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to split the values of a column in a pyspark dataframe. Consider that the column size is having values such as '15ML', '20GM' etc. I want them to be splitted in a such a way that, the output values after splitting becomes '15 ML' and '20 GM'. So, basically I'm trying to split the numerical value and it's unit. Please help me by proving a solution for this issue.

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
|size          |new_size(after splitting)|
+--------------+-------------------------+
|         100MG|                   100 MG|
|           1EA|                     1 EA|
|         100MG|                   100 MG|
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

I have inserted the sample data and the final column format I require. Thanks in advance

I tried using the below code, but I was not getting a proper result from this.

`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split 

df_f = products_size_df.withColumn("new_size", split(products_size_df.size, "MG"))
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a udf to split numbers and alphabets characters in a string:

```
import re

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
data = [["100MG"], ["1EA"], ["100MG"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("size")

def split_func(str):
    return re.sub("[A-Za-z]+", lambda ele: " " + ele[0] + " ", str)

split_udf = udf(split_func)

df.withColumn("splitted", split_udf(col("size"))).show()

+-----+--------+
| size|splitted|
+-----+--------+
|100MG| 100 MG |
|  1EA|   1 EA |
|100MG| 100 MG |
+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to add space between value and its unit, you can use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) like this:

```py
products_size_df.withColumn("new_size", regexp_replace(products_size_df.size, '(\d+)', '$1 '))
```

$1 refers to the number of group, so basically you just find value and add space after it

---

If you need to create new columns for value and unit, you can take  [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) like this:

```py
products_size_df.withColumn("new_value", regexp_extract(products_size_df.size, '(\d*)', 1))

products_size_df.withColumn("new_unit", regexp_extract(products_size_df.size, '([A-Za-z]+)', 1))
```

make notice that it will return empty string instead NULL if group won't be found, and NULL will be returned only if column has NULL value itself

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!! There was one more issue with the period(.) in between the numbers. But solved it. Anyway thanks for the solution.